# Cannot use register eax in assembly

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

at the beginning of my code I tried to do:

```
mov [eax],0
```

and got a segfault.

I think I have to initialize eax before, but I don't know how to do it.

Edit: More generally, I want to use a 32-bit register to calculate things. No matter which one.

help??

thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why `mov [eax], 0`, not `mov eax, 0`? Do you understand the difference between those?

Answer (score 3):

`mov [eax],0` moves zero to the memory addressed by the value `eax`. (In C terms, `*eax = 0;`.) You're writing to an address to which you don't have permission to write.

`mov eax,0` moves zero into `eax`. (In C terms, `eax = 0;`.) Is that what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

If an all purpose register of an instruction is placed between brackets[], then the assembler will be interprete the register as an addressregister and the value of the register as an offset-address where the instruction is pointing to, together with the segment part of the address.

Example:

```
BLUB dd 0FFFFFFFFh  ; a 32 bit value is stored in a memmory location

; Loading the segment part of the address into a segmentregister
; Note: an instruction of "mov segmentregister,immediate value" does not exist
; and so we have to use an all purpose register, or a memory location for to
; load the segment part of an address into a segmentregister

mov ax,SEG BLUB     ; load the segment-address into the AX-Register
mov ds,ax           ; load the segment-address form AX into DS-Register

mov eax,OFFSET BLUB ; load the offset part of the address into EAX

; load the value where the address-pair of DS:EAX is pointing to into EBX
mov ebx,[eax]
```

But if we only want to use some register for a calculation, then we can simple load immediate values into the all purpose register.

Example:

```
mov al,0FFh         ; low byte of AX
mov ah,0FFh         ; high byte of AX
mov ax,0FFFFh       ; low word of EAX
mov eax,0FFFFFFFFh  ; dword
```